# Javascript sound routing

Tags: javascript, audio

Simple question : is there a JS API that allows me to route sound into a specific output ? It seems the web audio api can't do this as the audiocontext destination is a readonly parameter that takes the default output.

Many thanks.

Comment: Good questions often include some code. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to clarify your question and help answerers know what is needed.

Comment: There's no code to provide as I didn't write any yet. I want to know if there is, or not, an api that does sound routing, then I will start to write some.

Comment: If this isn't the place to ask my question, please tell me where I should

Comment: What do you mean by specific output? Do you mean like only outputting to the left stereo speaker for example?

Comment: I mean on a specific device that is detected on windows sound panel. To be more specific, I have a usb sound card plugged, and I want my program to be able to play sound through this device while another program is playing other sounds through the pc sound card.
CheVolume is an external software that does it, but there is no way to save configuration, so I'd like my program to handle this directly.